# I need help solving why Entity Framework won't save if I add the virtual keyword to a property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created an open source project called Random Data Generator:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/RandomDataGenerator.

I also posted a short 6 minute video so you can see if this is worth cloning or not: https://youtu.be/7XEXWhEW_Fw

[Random Data Generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqnI8.jpg)

Random Data Generator is a sample project to demonstrate how much faster my open source project DataTier.Net is compared to Entity Framework because DataTier.Net uses all stored procedures.

This project is finished and working, but before I start bragging that DataTier.Net (https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataTier.Net) saves x times faster than EF, I want to make sure I am giving EF property representation. I admit I copied the data context from another project of mine that works and modified it but probably left out something.

If any Super Hero (EF Man ?) Entity Framework aficionados have a few minutes to take a look it might save vague answers since the code and database are published.

I think this is because I am tired, but if I add the virtual keyword to the Address property, Entity Framework stops saving the Member object, so I had to make one pass to save the Member and then another to save the Address.

(stops saving anything)

```
public virtual Address Address
{
   get; set;
}
```

I have the relationship established between the two tables (I think):

(this might be easier 
   USE [RandomData]
   GO

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Address]    Script Date: 8/16/2019 2:57:43 AM     
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MemberId] [int] NOT NULL,
[StreetAddress] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Unit] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[StateId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ZipCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Address] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
```

ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Member]    Script Date: 8/16/2019 2:57:43 AM 
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Member](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Member] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Member] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Member_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)) 
FOR 
[Active]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_Member] 
FOREIGN KEY([MemberId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Member] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_Member]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_State] 
FOREIGN KEY([StateId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[State] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_State]
GO
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virtual` has nothing to do with the issue (it controls the lazy loading behavior which is irrelevant here). The sample EF model simply does not match the sample database model. And when using existing database, correct mapping of the entity model is crucial for proper EF functioning.

Because all EF runtime behaviors (query generation, insert/update/delete operations and their order of execution etc.) are based on the entity model built from conventions, data annotations and fluent configuration, rather than the actual database.

Let take your current entity model in question (with all unnecessary explicit fields/properties removed):

```
public partial class Member
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public partial class Address
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsNew => this.Id < 1;
}
```

PKs and primitive properties are ok. But the relationship between `Member` and `Address` is not, which prevents correctly saving the data.

In EF, properties that refer to another entity or collection of another entities are called *navigation properties* and represent the corresponding end of the relationship along with the cardinality (one or many).

In your case, the navigation property is `Member.Address`. Actually it would have been, if there wasn't `[NotMapped]` attribute. With that attribute you are telling EF to ignore that property in *all* operations, like if it doesn't exist.

The effect in this case is that from EF point of view there is *no* relationship between the `Address` and `Member`, hence EF cannot correctly handle the insert operation, which requires getting the actual inserted identity value and using it as FK in the dependent entity record insert. It can be seen if you generate EF migration from the above:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Address",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            City = c.String(),
            MemberId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            StateId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            StreetAddress = c.String(),
            ZipCode = c.String(),
            Unit = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Member",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Active = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            FirstName = c.String(),
            LastName = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

As you can see, there are just create tables with columns, but no FK constraint.

So the first step will be to remove the `[NotMapped]` attribute. And now comes the real problem. The FK relationship in the database without unique constraint on `MemberId` column implies one-to-**many** relationship, i.e. one `Member` can have many `Address`es, hence the navigation property cannot be a single `Address`, but collection:

```
public partial class Member
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Now the EF migration fully matches the database (note the `.ForeignKey` declaration):

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Address",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            City = c.String(),
            MemberId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            StateId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            StreetAddress = c.String(),
            ZipCode = c.String(),
            Unit = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Member", t => t.MemberId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.MemberId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Member",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Active = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            FirstName = c.String(),
            LastName = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

Now the model matches the database and you can create members along with one or more associated addresses. But that requires changing your code which seems to assume member having zero or one address, i.e. one-to-one relationship.

If one-to-one is the intended relationship, then the database design is not appropriate. The best for such scenario (and naturally supported by EF) is the so called [Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations) where instead of separate FK `MemberId`, the PK of `Address` is also used as FK.

This would be the best design for EF. Unfortunately this requires database design change, hence cannot be used with the common database you are using for comparison.

There is a way to keep the database design as is and create the desired one-to-one mapping (although technically not enforced in database). That requires *mapping* `Address` property of `Member` as *reference navigation property*, removing explicit FK property `MemberId` from `Address` class (EF6 limitation) and mapping the FK column as *shadow property* using fluent API:

```
public partial class Member
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //[NotMapped] <-- remove this
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public partial class Address
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    //public int MemberId { get; set; } <-- remove this
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsNew => this.Id < 1;
}
```

and inside `OnModelCreation` override:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.Address)
    .WithRequired()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("MemberId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Now a code like this will create both `Member` and associated `Address`:

```
var member = new Member
{
    FirstName = "FN1",
    LastName = "LN1",
    Address = new Address
    {
        City = "C1",
        Unit = "U1",
        ZipCode = "ZC1",
        StreetAddress = "SA1",
    }
};
dbContext.Set<Member>().Add(member);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

---

To recap:

EF is more strict to how you define the relationships and their cardinality, because many runtime behaviors depend on that. Proper mapping is a must in order to get correct operation handling.

Also as a side note, the CUD performance is definitely not one of the EF strengths, so comparing it with another library IMHO doesn't make much sense. It has many other advantages, and if needed, the performance of the CUD operations can significantly be improved with some 3rd party extensions for batch insert/update/delete.

Comment: That's such a stunningly good answer, I feel like I learned EF even though I know nothing about it other than the concept.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will add the relationship.

I added the not mapped because it wasn't saving with it, but your answer explains why.

Having me represent EF is like Nancy Pelosi representing the Republican Party.

This why I asked for some help. Many thanks.

Comment: Lol, glad being helpful :)

Comment: I understand the use of Create Table if the table already exists.

I am not using Code First, so is that still needed?

Thanks

Comment: Also, I can change my database. I just made this for a demo project.

Comment: The migration code was shown just to see how the database will look if created from your entity model. You don't need that code when using existing database. It's for verification that EF model and database match.